# How to make DropDown Menu that shows all Drop Levels at once?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I wonder how to build such a menu:

http://de.tinypic.com/r/2udvkwo/5

so all droplevels are shown when clicking on one of the main categories!

Help, please! ! !

Greetings, Pina